# Python find specific words and objects in text and converts them to csv

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

I get a messed up text, I need to extract the specified content and then output a new csv，it looks like this

```
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="border-bottom-grey-1 margin-bottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin-bottom">
<h6 class="text-red margin-bottom-1">lolita</h6>
<h6>name : jeri</h6>
<h6>phone : 0123456789 , 0987654321</h6>
<h6>mail : tjeri@totalmaker.com</h6>
</div>
```

I want to extract name, phone, email and convert it to csv file so it looks like this

```
name;phone;mail
jeri;0123456789,0987654321;tjeri@totalmaker.com
```

Comment: Looks like the definition of a _Beautiful Soup_ application. Have you tried that library? Please show relevant script.

Comment: Yes, it's Beautiful Soup, it has a lot of the same class objects, I can't grab the name, email, phone, I can only deal with it by looking up keywords

Comment: To reach the level [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you would better provide the script snippet you are trying